# How to run Mac app with parameters written on AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

There is a simple script with method. Method accepts parameter and return value. Via script editor I did export to application and have TestParam.app folder(application).

Question: How I can run this application via Terminal?
Goal: pass parameter and get response

Yes, I already did some search in the Internet and still not able to run. Do I have to change signature for another one?

```
on displayError(theErrorMessage)
    display dialog theErrorMessage
    return "done"
end displayError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the handler with `osascript`. Load the application as script object and run the handler

```
osascript -e 'set scriptAlias to alias "Macintosh HD:Applications:TestParam.app:"' -e 'set theScript to load script scriptAlias' -e 'displayError("Hello") of theScript'
```

Comment: I am not good with AppleScript - please explain what is ""Macintosh HD:Applications:TestParam.app:"" - is it a pass to application?

Comment: This is the HFS path (colon separated) to the application.

Comment: Dear, it wooooooorks! Thank you a lot! Could you explain why so complicated way? I tried other simple one and they did not work, but this work! A lot of emotions due a lot of time wasted to do it

Comment: As I said you have to load the script as script object with the `load script` command and run the handler of the script passing the parameter.

Comment: would it be slower as just run whole not compiled AppleScript?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: I run just already compiled app and my algorithm works well for 4 seconds, when I use asascript with inserting parameters it takes 15 seconds, what is very sad... So, the question is - would be this idea to run app with osascript also slow?

Comment: I don't know, test it.

Answer (score 0):

The **run** handler of a script can also accept (multiple) arguments, which would be passed on when running it via `osascript`.  For example, enter the following script in the **Script Editor** and save it somewhere:

```
on run arguments
    if (count arguments) is 0 then set arguments to {"no arguments"} -- none passed
    repeat with anItem in arguments -- (arguments is a list, even if there is only one)
            displayError(anItem)
    end repeat
    -- the last result will be returned
end run

on displayError(theErrorMessage)
    display dialog theErrorMessage
    return "done"
end displayError
```

Then from the **Terminal**, it can be run like any other shell utility by doing something like:

```
osascript /path/to/your/script 'this is a test'  # other arguments as desired
```

where `/path/to/your/script` would be the actual path to the script (you can also drag the script icon into the **Terminal** to paste its path).